# WPF bind combobox to dependency method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a Page with a repository [dependency](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#whatis), and a Combobox in the page I want to bind to a certain method of the dependency

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    private Dependency dep {get; set;} //method: GetAll() - returns IEnumerable<Foo>
...
}
```

I would like to bind the combobox in the xaml rather than in the code behind.

It seems I have to point the DataContext property of the page to the page itself

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

But after that I have no idea on how to continue.

Obviously in the codebehind it would be

```
mycombobox.ItemsSource = dep.GetAll();
mycombobox.DisplayValuePath = "FooName";
mycombobox.SelectedValuePath = "FooId";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what class `Dependency` is, but how about just adding another property, that you can bind to:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public Dependency Dep { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> AllDeps
    {
        get { return Dep.GetAll(); }
    }
}
```

Now you could bind a ComboBox like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllDeps}" />
```

As an alternative, you may declare `AllDeps` as ObservableCollection, and add elements when needed:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public Dependency Dep { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> AllDeps { get; set; }

    public MyPage()
    {
        AllDeps = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
        InitializeComponent();

        // initialize Dep

        foreach (var d in Dep.GetAll())
        {
            AllDeps.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. The binding happens before or after the `InitializeComponents()` method?

Comment: In this simplistic approach, `Dep` should have been initialized before InitializeComponent, because the bindings are established during the execution of that method. You can set a breakpoint in the `AllDeps` getter to find out when it is called exactly.